# print at the command line, how can I print landscape

Tags: macos, printing

Just using lp filename.txt and it's going to my local printer

How can I do something like `lp filename.txt -format=landscape` or `lpl filename.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man lp`:

```
       -o landscape
```

Looks like it should do what you need :)